# Import Tycho “pomless” project into Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, pom.xml, tycho

We have a project based on Maven Tycho and we recently eliminated all these seemingly redundant `pom.xml` files. The command line build works fine, so this seemed like a good improvement to remove useless clutter.

Later we found out that these projects cannot be easily imported into Eclipse any more -- at least not the way we were used to. So far, we used the import “Existing Maven Projects” command and all directories which contained a `pom.xml` got imported. As there are not `pom.xml` files any more, this does not work. D’oh!

What’s the recommended way to import pomless Tycho projects into Eclipse?

Comment: Probably you just missed to share the `.project` files and the `.settings` folders. Having the `.project` files you can just import it as exisiting Eclipse projects (e.g. via _File > Open Projects from File System..._).

Comment: @howlger Ha. Admittedly this hadn’t even come to my mind, as I’m normally always used to just `.gitignore` these. I’ll try this, thank you! :-)

Comment: The `.project` files and the `.settings` folders are intended to be shared. That is why Eclipse stores them in the project directory. [It is a common misconception to .gitignore them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60669809/6505250).

Answer (score 4):

The Maven import is only for (plain Java) projects that contain a `pom.xml` file, not for projects that will be build with Tycho (independent whether they are POM-less or not).

A Maven build with the Maven plugin Tycho behaves quite differently than a regular Maven build. Resolving dependencies, downloading dependencies and compiling is done by Tycho and also the phases differ from a regular Maven build. You need some basic OSGi knowledge (where in contrast to Maven, dependencies are also resolved at runtime since bundles/plugins can be started and stopped at runtime). The vogella company provides a quite good Tycho tutorial with a [sample Git repository](https://github.com/vogellacompany/tycho-example) which might a good start (requires basic OSGi knowledge): [*Maven Tycho for building Eclipse plug-ins, OSGi bundles and Eclipse applications with the command line - Tutorial*](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html)

A **`.project` file per project is needed** to be able to import such Plug-in, Fragment, Feature, Update Site, etc. projects e.g.

- in the ***Git Repositories* view**, by **right-clicking** a repository and choosing ***Import Projects...*** or
- via *File > Open Projects from File System...*.

If you have lost the `.project` files, **copy them from a project of the same kind/nature** and adapt `<name>...</name>` (this is the name that is shown in Eclipse, in most cases the name of the project folder, and it must be unique; two projects with the same name cannot be opened).

A *Plug-in* project that contains Java code also needs a `.classpath` file, which you can add in the same way after importing.

By not sharing the `.settings` folders you lost the settings that can be done in *Project > Properties* (it is recommended to have project specific settings at least for *Java Compiler* and *Java Compiler > Errors/Warnings*).