# Ship an eclipse dynamic web project as a pure maven project (possible?)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a maven project in eclipse (was originally a dynamic web project, which was converted to a maven project that has the web-app arch type).

Whenever I upload the project to Github, I, of course, upload the source java and web files, pom.xml, but I also need to upload the .project, .settings, and .classpath files which are Eclipse IDE specific (right?), so that later I can import it directly using eclipse from Github. If the latter files are not uploaded, I cannot import the project later on in eclipse. After importing, I use maven with the respective pom.xml file to download the dependencies and build the war file.

Is there a way to export my project in a form independent from eclipse, i.e., something like a pure maven project? So that, later, it can be imported using e.g., say Intellij or Netbeans only using maven? Or just tell Eclipse to import a maven project from Git, rather than an Eclipse project as it is now. Is there such a thing? If so, how to create it and commit it to Github from Eclipse? Which files/directories do I (not) need?

Comment: As long as the files are maintained, they should be under version control. They are also used by VS Code and when not used, they do not cause problems and they do not preventing using other IDEs. The `pom.xml` file (which by the way is also a tool specific file and not Java standard) serves other purposes than these files (even when there are some overlaps). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60669809/6505250

Comment: With m2e-wtp installed, Eclipse should already be able to import your Maven projects from your local git clones.