# VS Code Java Debugger Making a Lot of Untracked Files

Tags: java, git, visual-studio-code

I actually don't remember what I did/installed precisely, but it should be something along the line of "installing Java Debugger". This is giving me a lot of(more than one thousand) `.project` untracked files, even if I delete them, they pop back up again.

[image: pic] [image: pic2]

Edit: Just found this link: [What project files does Visual Studio Code create via its Java extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53509715/what-project-files-does-visual-studio-code-create-via-its-java-extensions) , it seems like the question is the situation I'm in right now, but the answer is still very confusing. So what should I do?

Thank you!

Comment: Try to turn the java to **lightweight mode**, you can enable it via `"java.server.launchMode": "LightWeight"`in .vscode/settings.json. Detailed information please have a look at the [reply](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/618#issuecomment-611842041) about the github issue: [Any way to get rid of .project .classpath .settings/ files?](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/618)

Comment: Also, there's another [fix](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/618#issuecomment-749324109) other user provided that you can have a try.

Comment: @MollyWang Thank you! Solution one is a way to go but then it doesn't load the Java debugger, so I think that's a problem, because I need to use this to run my application. Second one works as well, I just need to make sure I can find all the patterns. Will give them a try, again, thanks!